# Event isn't removed from Listener in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I'm developing a drag'n'clone feature for my flash app (AS3 and Flash CS5). The clones are created perfectly, but when I try to drag the clone recently created, the app creates a new clone (and allow me to drag it).

I want to remove this behaviour: clone only should be drag and dropped, not cloned. My code is:

```
public class Car extends MovieClip
    {

        // imports...

        public function Car()
        {
            addListeners();
        }

        private function addListeners():void
        {
            this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,clone);
        }

        private function clone(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            // Clone the object
            var newcar = new e.target.constructor;
            newcar.graphics.copyFrom(this.graphics);
            newcar.x = this.x;
            newcar.y = this.y;

            this.parent.addChild(newcar);

            newcar.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,dragCar);
            newcar.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,dropCar);
        }

        private function dragCar(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            e.target.startDrag();
        }

        private function dropCar(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            e.target.stopDrag();

                    // This line doesn't remove the event, and I don't know why
            e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,clone);

            e.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, dragCar);
            e.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,dropCar);

        }

    }
```

I hope someone can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here as you are creating a new instance of Car in the clone function, the constructor of that new Car object is called which in turn calls `addListeners()` and the clone has a MOUSE_DOWN event listener that again clones the clone. That is why you have the problem you describe.

To avoid this you need to add the following line in you clone function (**this does not work see below edit**)

```
newcar.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,clone);
```

this removes the clone event listener from the cloned (new) Car instance and avoids cloning again.

Also to start drag you should do it in MOUSE_DOWN instead of MOUSE_MOVE.

**Update**
OK I see, MOUSE_DOWN is not called Again for the clone, so you need to use MOUSE_MOVE. Thus in this case I would remove the MOUSE_MOVE listener in the listener's body so that it is only called once.

**Update**
This seems to remove the event listener.

```
newcar.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, newcar.clone);
```

You have to refer to the newcar instance's clone method `newcar.clone` to remove the event listener.

**Working Code**
The following code is working just fine

```
package{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.*;
    public class Car extends MovieClip
    {
        public function Car()
        {
            addListeners();
        }

        private function addListeners():void
        {
            this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,clone);
        }

        private function clone(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            // Clone the object
            var newcar = new e.target.constructor;
            newcar.graphics.copyFrom(this.graphics);
            newcar.x = this.x;
            newcar.y = this.y;

            this.parent.addChild(newcar);

            // remove the clone listener
            newcar.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, newcar.clone);

            // add dragging listeners
            newcar.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, dragCar);
            newcar.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropCar);

            // this is used for dragging the clone
            newcar.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragCar);
        }

        private function dragCar(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            // if a MOUSE_MOVE event listener is registered remove it
        if(e.target.hasEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE))
            e.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, dragCar);
            e.target.startDrag();
        }

        private function dropCar(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            e.target.stopDrag();

            // do not remove the listener if you want the clone to be dragable
            // e.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,dropCar);
        }
    }
}
```

**Keep clone dragable**
For this in the above code I have added a MOUSE_DOWN event listener for dragging the clone

```
newcar.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragCar);
```

And commented out the `e.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,dropCar);` in `dropCar`

Also added a Check before removing MOUSE_MOVE listener as to whether it is there or not, as this function will be called later by MOUSE_DOWN also.

Comment: So, I'm removing the event, but it stills there. How can I solve it? Thanks!

Comment: look at the update to my answer, we need to refer to the `clone` function of `newcar` instance as `newcar.clone`

Comment: Thanks mate, but now I can't drag and drop the clone, and I want to do it. How can I do it? Thanks so much.

Comment: I was curious why were you removing the event listeners for drag drop support. I thought you did not want the clones to be dragged. I will update my answer so clones can be dragged.